# I want to improve my select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have these two SQL select statements; can any one help me to make them in one select statement?

```sql
SELECT Misstion.Mis_Link, Misstion.Mis_Disc, Misstion.Mis_Title,
Misstion_User.MU_UserID, Misstion.Mis_StartDate, Misstion.Mis_EndDate,
Misstion_User.MU_ID, Misstion.Mis_ID, Misstion_User.MU_Date,
Misstion_User.MU_Type
FROM           
Misstion_User INNER JOIN
Misstion ON Misstion_User.MU_MisstionID = Misstion.Mis_ID
WHERE (Misstion_User.MU_UserID = 2) AND (Misstion.Mis_StartDate =
CONVERT(date, GETDATE())) AND (Misstion.Mis_EndDate > CONVERT(date,
GETDATE()))
```

---

```sql
SELECT User_Group.UserID, Misstion.Mis_Title, Misstion.Mis_Disc,
Misstion.Mis_Link, Misstion.Mis_StartDate, Misstion.Mis_EndDate
FROM User_Group INNER JOIN
Misstion_User ON User_Group.Group_ID = Misstion_User.MU_Type INNER JOIN
Misstion ON Misstion_User.MU_MisstionID = Misstion.Mis_ID
WHERE (User_Group.UserID = 2) AND (Misstion.Mis_StartDate =
CONVERT(date, GETDATE())) AND (Misstion.Mis_EndDate > CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: What do you mean "one statement", the resulting data seems to be different.

Comment: Show us sample result from each query, and how you want to combine them.

Comment: i want to merge this two statement together

Comment: Merge how? Show us how...

Comment: i have table Mission in this table i give misstion to user or to a group (MU_Type) Group ID in first select i get misstion detail When user_ID = My User in second select i get detail when user in group take this mission.... so i want if this user is in group or single preview the mission detail

Comment: You still don't want to add some sample result, and show how to combine them? How do you expect us to understand what you want? Or, don't you know what you want? Have you just been asked to solve a problem that neither you nor your boss understand?

Comment: the result is the same the different in if this user is single or in group

Comment: Mis_Link        Mis_Disc       Mis_Title    MU_UserID   Mis_StartDate   Mis_EndDate  MU_ID   Mis_ID   MU_Date       MU_Type
www.ddd.com    vdssdfcsdfc      testttttt         2      2016-09-20     2016-09-21      1      4       2016-09-20      0      as Single User

------------------------------------

MU_UserID    Mis_Title     Mis_Disc     Mis_Link       Mis_StartDate   Mis_EndDate                as member in grpup
     2       trayyyyyyyy   dfdfgsdgsd   www.sss.com      2016-09-20     2016-09-21

Comment: Please provide the table structure.

Comment: Do your existing queries work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

A very crud description but from my intuition I think you want something like below..

```
SELECT        
User_Group.UserID, 
Misstion.Mis_Title, 
Misstion.Mis_Disc, 
Misstion.Mis_Link, 
Misstion.Mis_StartDate, 
Misstion.Mis_EndDate,
Misstion_User.MU_ID, 
Misstion.Mis_ID, 
Misstion_User.MU_Date, 
Misstion_User.MU_Type
FROM User_Group User_Group
INNER JOIN Misstion_User Misstion_User ON User_Group.Group_ID = Misstion_User.MU_Type 
INNER JOIN Misstion Misstion ON Misstion_User.MU_MisstionID = Misstion.Mis_ID
WHERE (User_Group.UserID = 2) AND (Misstion_User.MU_UserID = 2) AND (Misstion.Mis_StartDate = CONVERT(date, GETDATE())) AND (Misstion.Mis_EndDate > CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: now result found,some time user get mission as one user or as group member

Comment: please be more specific. don't understand your comment.

Comment: target for this select is to get mission for user .....this user may be single user or group user .... so i want to select mission for this user if he is single or group .... first select to select as single 2nd to select as group member

Comment: @SedekaMahmoud Please provide Table structure and if possible sample data and output.